# How to load next Image while user is looking at first image in the TabView pages carousel with AsyncImageView In SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have an images carousel that fetching heavy images from a few URLs and displaying asynchronously when user is going to the next page. And the problem is that user need to see a waiting wheel and wait to see the next image.

So the ideal case would be to eliminate the waiting wheel by loading the next image while user still seeing the fist image and I don't know how to do it properly.

If you know the solution please let me know, I will mean a lot to me.

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedImageToSee: Int = 0
    private let imagesUrl: [String] = [
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633125195723-04860dde4545?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4032&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzNDIyMDUyMQ&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=3024",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633090332452-532d6b39422a?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4032&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8fHx8fHx8MTYzNDIyMDI1Ng&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=3024",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1591667954789-c25d5affec59?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4032&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8bmF0dXJlLGNhcnN8fHx8fHwxNjM0MjIwNzU1&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=3024",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580316576539-aee1337e80e8?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4032&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8bmF0dXJlLGNhcnN8fHx8fHwxNjM0MjIwNzk5&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=3024",
        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484976063837-eab657a7aca7?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=4032&ixid=MnwxfDB8MXxyYW5kb218MHx8bmF0dXJlLGNhcnN8fHx8fHwxNjM0MjIwNjky&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&utm_campaign=api-credit&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=unsplash_source&w=3024"
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ImagesCaruselView(selectedImageToSee: $selectedImageToSee, urls: imagesUrl)
    }
}

struct ImagesCaruselView: View {
    @Binding var selectedImageToSee: Int
    let urls: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedImageToSee) {
            ForEach(0..<urls.count, id: \.self) { url in
                AsyncImageView(
                    url: URL(string: urls[url])!,
                    placeholder: { ProgressView().scaleEffect(1.5).progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .gray)) },
                    image: { Image(uiImage: $0) }
                )
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
        .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}

struct AsyncImageView<Placeholder: View>: View {
    @StateObject private var loader: ImageLoader
    private let placeholder: Placeholder
    private let image: (UIImage) -> Image
    
    init(
        url: URL,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Placeholder,
        @ViewBuilder image: @escaping (UIImage) -> Image = Image.init(uiImage:)
    ) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder()
        self.image = image
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: ImageLoader(url: url, cache: Environment(\.imageCache).wrappedValue))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .onAppear(perform: loader.load)
    }
    
    private var content: some View {
        Group {
            if loader.image != nil {
                image(loader.image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            } else {
                placeholder
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol ImageCache {
    subscript(_ url: URL) -> UIImage? { get set }
}

struct TemporaryImageCache: ImageCache {
    private let cache: NSCache<NSURL, UIImage> = {
        let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()
        cache.countLimit = 100 // 100 items
        cache.totalCostLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 200 // 200 MB
        return cache
    }()
    
    subscript(_ key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get { cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL) }
        set { newValue == nil ? cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSURL) : cache.setObject(newValue!, forKey: key as NSURL) }
    }
}

import Combine

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    private(set) var isLoading = false
    
    private let url: URL
    private var cache: ImageCache?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    private static let imageProcessingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "image-processing")
    
    init(url: URL, cache: ImageCache? = nil) {
        self.url = url
        self.cache = cache
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard !isLoading else { return }

        if let image = cache?[url] {
            self.image = image
            return
        }
        
        #warning("Caching the image are disabled")
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [weak self] _ in self?.onStart() },
//                          receiveOutput: { [weak self] in self?.cache($0) },
                          receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in self?.onFinish() },
                          receiveCancel: { [weak self] in self?.onFinish() })
            .subscribe(on: Self.imageProcessingQueue)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
    
    private func onStart() {
        isLoading = true
    }
    
    private func onFinish() {
        isLoading = false
    }
    
    private func cache(_ image: UIImage?) {
        image.map { cache?[url] = $0 }
    }
}

import SwiftUI

struct ImageCacheKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: ImageCache = TemporaryImageCache()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var imageCache: ImageCache {
        get { self[ImageCacheKey.self] }
        set { self[ImageCacheKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to do is create a Model that will asynchronously load the images so that you have control over when the image is downloaded as opposed to relying on `AsyncImageView` to handle the asynchronicity for you.

Comment: oh, got it. Thanks a lot for a hint. I still struggle to get this right

Comment: @ScottThompson I'm stuck, could you help me to achieve it please?